# What is the meaning of the statement"centre of mass of a body remains in equilibrium"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, free-body-diagram

[image]

Explain the meaning of statement"centre of mass of body remains in equilibrium if total the total external force on the body is zero".what is exactly meant by the term equilibrium  here?

Comment: Do you know what the center of mass (COM) is?

Comment: To be honest, I think the meaning of that statement is that the book you're using isn't very good... that is a vague and somewhat misleading way of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the center of mass (CM) for a system of $k$ particles is defined as: $\vec R_{CM} = {{\sum_{i = 1}^{k} m_i \vec r_i} \over {M}} $ where $m_i$ is the mass of the $i^{th}$ particle, $\vec r_i$ is the position of the $i^{th}$ particle from a point defined as the origin, and $M = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} m_i$ is the total mass of the sytem. The total momentum of the system $\vec P = M \dot {\vec R}_{CM}$. The acceleration of the CM $\ddot {\vec R}_{CM} = {\vec F \over M}$ where $\vec F$ is the net external force on the system.

With no net external force, the total momentum of the system $\vec P$ is constant.  Therefore, no matter the internal forces, the velocity of the center of mass remains constant if no net external force is applied.  The CM moves as a single particle with mass equal to the total mass of the system, acted on by a force equal to the net external force on the system.

Equilibrium means that the velocity of the center of mass of a body remains constant with no net external force.  If the center of mass has zero velocity, the velocity of the center of mass will remain zero and the position of the center of mass will not move regardless of internal forces that act on the body.  For example, for an artillery shell that is at rest, if it explodes the CM of the shell will not move.